# I am trying to understand this piece of TypeScript code

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, observable

I have this template showing these posts:

```html
<div class="card mb-3" *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{post.title}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{post.body}}</p>
    <button (click)="removePost(post)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
    <button (click)="editPost(post)" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The remove function is using a service named servicePost to remove posts

```ts
removePost(post: Post) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      this.postService.removePost(post.id).subscribe(() => {
        this.posts.forEach((current, index) => {
          if (post.id === current.id) {
            this.posts.splice(index, 1);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

And the service itself

```ts
export class PostService {
      postsUrl: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      removePost(post: Post | number): Observable<Post> {
        const id = typeof post === 'number' ? post : post.id;
        const url = `${this.postsUrl}/${id}`;

        return this.http.delete<Post>(url, httpOptions);  
      }
```

I really do not understand this part:

```ts
removePost(post: Post | number): Observable<Post> {
const id = typeof post === 'number' ? post : post.id;
```

So far I have understood that the author is trying to extract the `post.id` so they can use it to assemble the `return this.http.delete<Post>(url, httpOptions);` and delete the record.

I do not understand how the above code works. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)?

Comment: You can invoke the removePost in two ways, `removePost(post)` (where post is a **Post** object) and `removePost(35)` (where 35 is the id of the post).
With that line, the author tries ot understand what type is the parameter and, according to that, use the id or extracts the id from the object

Comment: @danday74 @John @Cristian So If the whole object is passed, not a number, then use post.id but if a number is passed then that is the id itself so use post as is.  So if It was ` <button (click)="removePost(post.id)" ...> ` instead of ` <button (click)="removePost(post)"...>` then I could use only a number as type to `removePosts(post: number) ` and `const id = post.id.`
So he chooses to be on the safe side by expecting either the whole object or only the id. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 3):

Remove post is triggered by clicking on the `<button (click)="removePost(post)" ...>`

The removePost method in turn calls the `postService.removePost` which makes an HTTP request and returns an Observable of the response.

In that method ...

TypeScript allows you to define multiple types. So in this case post must be of type Post OR type number.

If the post is of type number then set the id to the number given. If it is of type Post then use the id property from the post object (`post.id`).

```
removePost(post: Post | number): Observable<Post> {
const id = typeof post === 'number' ? post : post.id;
```

Then finally, in the .subscribe() block back in the removePost method the HTTP response is received (but ignored). The function inside subscribe is called only on an HTTP success which means on the backend server the delete has taken place. So he does a splice to remove the post from the frontend data.

Answer (score 1):

```
removePost(post: Post | number)
```

This is a function that takes one parameter.  That parameter can be either a `Post` object or a simple number.

```
const id = typeof post === 'number' ? post : post.id;
```

This part decides how to determine the ID.  Presumably, if the parameter is a number, that is the ID itself, while if you give it an object it has to get it from the object's properties, so it has to check the type to know which way to do it.  If the ternary syntax confuses you, it can be roughly rewritten like this:

```
let id // changed to let because you can't declare a const without assigning it immediately
if (typeof post === 'number') {
    id = post
} else {
    id = post.id
}
```